# How to select rows with certain values in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a strucutred array that looks like this:

```
>>> arr
array([(1619449020, 1047, 50.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619449080, 1048, 40.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619449140, 1049, 30.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619449200, 1050, 20.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       ...
       (1619472360, 1436, 10.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619472420, 1437, 20.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619472480, 1438, 30.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619472540, 1439, 40.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.)],
      dtype=[('time', '<i4'), ('idx', '<i4'), ('val1', '<f4'), ('val2', '<i4'), ('val3', '<i4'), ('val4', '<i4'), ('val5', '<f4')])
```

How could I select rows the 'idx' values of which correspond to certain values? For example, 1050, 1436, 1438.

I could just select each row per a value and concatenate them, but I wonder if there's any simpler way to do this.

Comment: hi trying to reproduce your array got a : arr = np.array([(1619449020, 1047, 50.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),

ValueError: field 'val1' occurs more than once ?? any clue about that ?

Comment: @pippo1980 Thank you for the comment! They are typos that I made while copying the code! ; )

Comment: I think you should remove the ellipsis as well. I got ```TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not callable```

Comment: yep sure, by the way whats wrong in structured arrays about arr.shape ??

Comment: @Nachiket the value error appers after you remove ellipsis (that is '...'), otherwise you get ellipsis error first

Answer (score 1):

my first attempt:

```
import numpy as np



arr = np.array(([(1619449020, 1047, 50.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619449080, 1048, 40.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619449140, 1049, 30.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619449200, 1050, 20.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619472360, 1436, 10.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619472420, 1437, 20.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619472480, 1438, 30.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.),
       (1619472540, 1439, 40.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.)]),dtype=[('time', '<i4'), ('idx', '<i4'), ('val1', '<f4'), ('val2', '<i4'), ('val3', '<i4'), 
                 ('val4', '<i4'), ('val5', '<f4')]) ## ----------> no w its OK

print(arr,'\n\ndtype = ', arr.dtype,'\n',arr.shape)



for i in arr:
    if (i['idx']) in  [1050 ,1436, 1438]:
        print(i)
```

output:

```
(1619449200, 1050, 20.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.)
(1619472360, 1436, 10.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.)
(1619472480, 1438, 30.8076, 0, 3, 3, 1.)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can either use the `filter` function or a list comprehension. For example (using a list comprehension):

```
focused = np.array([x for x in arr if x['idx'] in [1050, 1436, 1438]])
```

Comment: why arr.shape outputs (8,) instead of (8,7) ?  any way to get the arr.shape[1] somehow

Comment: @pippo1980 This is a one-dimensional list that happens to contain eight tuples. If we change the parentheses to brackets, we'll get the (8, 7) shape.

Comment: yep sure but won't be able to use the dtype=[('time', '<i4'), ('idx', '<i4'), ('val1', '<f4'), ('val2', '<i4'), ('val3', '<i4'), 
                 ('val4', '<i4'), ('val5', '<f4')]) without creating something I don't know what is it ?

Comment: isnt it more easy to use directly a dataframe ?